# Where is SQLCMD.EXE in SQL Server 2014 Express?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, sql-server-2014

Using "SQLCMD.EXE" to back up my SQL Server Express databases for years I just discovered that after installing the [2014 version](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=42299), I found no SQLCMD.EXE anymore.

In previous versions it was located at

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE

But in my 2014 installation, no SQLCMD.EXE exists in

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn

**My question:**

Any chance to get SQLCMD.EXE into SQL Server Express 2014?

Comment: What happens when you type sqlcmd in command prompt. Does that gives error ? I have 2014 exprees on my PC will check and revert but my guess is some change has been made.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Found this on [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/845620/sqlcmd-exe-relocated-in-2014-installation#):

> According to this page on MSDN
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143547(v=sql.120).aspx ,
>   sqlcmd.exe and bcp.exe are now in < Install Directory >\Client
>   SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn

Indeed, `sqlcmd.exe` and `bcp.exe` are in that folder in my machine.

Make sure you installed `Client SDK Tools`.

Comment: Thanks. Isn't it strange, that the folder is `110` for the `120` version?

Comment: I think it's because SQL client driver still on `110` version

Comment: The logical way to find it is now to check the "ODBCToolsPath" registry key, as mentioned in another post within the Microsoft Connect issue.