# Where is SQLCMD.EXE in SQL Server 2014 LocalDB or how to install it?

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd, sql-server-localdb

On a machine with SQL Server LocalDB 2014 installed I am looking for SQLCMD.EXE file but cannot find it anywhere. Is there a way how to install it separately?

Unfortunately I am not local admin of the machine, so I prefer no MSI...

Found this link https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=36433, but cannot use MSI...  Perhaps copying executable files and dlls can do the trick.

After copying files SQLCMD.EXE, BATCHPARSER.DLL and SQLCMD.RLL from `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn`  from another computer with SSMS installed I still get the error:

> Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : Data source name not found
>   and no default driver specified.

running `sqlcmd -S np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#F8040C8F\tsql\query`.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71949/where-is-sqlcmd-exe-in-sql-server-2014-express

Comment: Not applicable for LocalDB.

Comment: Unfortunately you'll probably need the MSI http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=36433 Otherwise, as with 2012, I would think you can go through the Installation Wizard http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2694/getting-started-with-sql-server-2012-express-localdb/

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal I think your ServerName is incorrect. I am able to connect (also using Native Client 11.0) via the following: `sqlcmd -S (localdb)\Projects -Q "SELECT DB_NAME(), @@SERVERNAME;"`. Essentially, unless something else is missing, LocalDB connections (as of .NET Framework v 4.5, I believe) are made using "(localdb)\{InstanceName}". If that works, I will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have figured out that during SQL Server LocalDB MSI installation **the ODBC driver** is not installed

So to use SQLCMD it is necessary to install 
[Microsoft® ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server®](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434) - it is a part of ODBC driver as per [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568447%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).

When I tried to install Microsoft® Command Line Utilities 11 for SQL Server® it prompted me to install the ODBC Driver first.

Then it is possible either to copy the files SQLCMD.EXE, BATCHPARSER.DLL and SQLCMD.RLL or to install [Microsoft® Command Line Utilities 11 for SQL Server®](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=36433).

Answer (score 0):

Are you installing SQL Server 2014 on a Windows installation with no previous version of SQL Server in?

Have a look at C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn

Comment: Does this suggestion apply to a LocalDB installation as well?

Comment: @AndriyM I do not find this answer useful because the problem is not locating `SQLCMD.EXE` file but installing ODBC driver which requires local admin rights.